# In R/Highcharts to have this output in a Column Chart?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I would like to create this chart whith highchart.

[image: bar chart]

The idea is that that smaller column be inside the bigger one for each country.

How can I achieve this?

This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
library(highcharter)

gapminder::gapminder %>%
  
  filter(year >= 1990,country %in% c('Chile','Argentina'))%>%     
  
  hchart(
    type = 'column',
    
    hcaes(x = year, y = gdpPercap, group = country),
    visible = TRUE,
    showInLegend = TRUE,
    name  = "",
    zIndex = 9999999,
    zoneAxis = 'x',
    color = 'blue'          
    
  ) %>%

  hc_subtitle(text = "") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(enabled = FALSE,title = FALSE) %>%
  hc_yAxis(enabled = FALSE,title = FALSE,
           labels = list(enabled = FALSE)) %>%
  
  hc_plotOptions(
    column = list(stacking = NULL,pointWidth = 10)
    
  )
```

I am trying to understand how can I change the columns positions.

Comment: Please see my revised answer for building with `hchart`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but I don't believe it can be done with `hchart`. Since you need to have different settings for each series. You need to use `hc_add_series` to add each individual series to the plot. Then set the groupPadding to .5 and adjust the pointWidth for each series.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)
library(highcharter)

dat = gapminder::gapminder %>%
  filter(year >= 1990,country %in% c('Chile','Argentina')) %>%
  mutate(year = as.factor(year))

highchart(type = "chart") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_add_series(dat[dat$country == "Chile",], hcaes(x = year, y = gdpPercap), type = "column",
                groupPadding = 0.5, pointWidth = 80, name = "Chile") %>%
  hc_add_series(dat[dat$country == "Argentina",], hcaes(x = year, y = gdpPercap), type = "column",
                groupPadding = 0.5, pointWidth = 40, name = "Argentina") %>%
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE)
```

[image]

**Revised answer**

Actually, it is possible using `hchart`. All you have to do is add the groupPadding/pointWidth params as vectors. Where the first position in the vector corresponds to the first grouped series. "Argentina" in this case.

```
gapminder::gapminder %>%
  
  filter(year >= 1990,country %in% c('Chile','Argentina'))%>%     
  hchart(
    type = 'column',
    hcaes(x = year, y = gdpPercap, group = country),
    visible = TRUE,
    showInLegend = TRUE,
    zIndex = 9999999,
    groupPadding = c(.5,.5), #length 2 vector for 2 groups
    pointWidth = c(80,40) #length 2 vector for 2 groups
  ) %>%
  hc_subtitle(text = "") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(enabled = FALSE,title = FALSE) %>%
  hc_yAxis(enabled = FALSE,title = FALSE,
           labels = list(enabled = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    column = list(stacking = NULL,pointWidth = 10)
  )
```